# IE: First list item smaller than rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

Any thoughts? The first list item is being squished, but only by IE. All of the other browsers are happy.

http://dev.torontofamilytherapist.com/services/

Comment: Please post the _relevant_ code.

Comment: Sorry Teemu, I'm not sure what that relevant code would be in this case, other than that which I can see in the inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your code in the IE Console. When I removed the checkbox next to `width:auto;` in bootstrap.css, the image expanded correctly.  While I'm not sure why this fixed the issue, it does fix it.
[image]

You'll want to override the CSS statement elsewhere.

```
.featured-thumbnail img { width: 100% important!; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Robbert has the correct answer but no reason. The reason why this is happening because the right two images are bigger than the container. The first one is not. Therefore it hits the `width:auto` and thus it is shrunk to the dimensions of the image.

Rather than changing the css, you can replace it with an image of the correct dimensions (370x264).

Answer (score 0):

If the image has smaller width than it's parent you need to put width: 100%; in order for image to cover entire container, otherwise width: auto; limits it to image actual size.